# laravel get a list of posts, with their tags, and comments

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**The answer to this is below.**

I am trying to get a list of say 10 posts, and add each posts tags and comments (which will vary depending on the post) I have an example of what I am trying to achieve below.

Essentially I am following this as a start. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

However its not quite working.Its set up verbatim and I have the pivot tables set up as described.  Either I can get all posts, but by 1 tag, or 1 post with all its tags. ie

```
"post_title": "Post 1 ",
    "tags": [
            {
                "tag_name": "Tag 1"
            },{
                "tag_name": "Tag 2"
            },...
```

I have also tried to use the join method but end up with this situation.

```
 [{ 
    "post_title": "Post 1 ", <--- post 1
    "tag_name": "Tag 1"
  },
  {
    "post_title": "Post 1 ", <--- Also post 1
    "tag_name": "Tag 2"
  },
  {
    "post_title": "Post 3 ",
    "tag_name": "Tag 2"
  },
  {
    "post_title": "Post 4 ",
    "tag_name": "Tag 1"
  }]
```

As you can see the first 2 have duplicate post names. I should have post 1 with both tags added.

The way I seem to be able to achieve this is to join everything, then modify, and group elements or even worse get the latest 10 posts, then extract the post ids into an array. 
Then with those post ids, get all the categories where the post ids match, 
Then repeat for comments. Then zip this together. This seems super clunky.

It's odd as this seems like it should be everywhere in google. If it is, sorry.

There has to be a simple solution for Laravel for me to get the structure below. The question is, is it better to use Eloquent or the join query from Database section to solve this problem?

```
[{ 
    "post_title": "Post 1 ", 
    "cat": [
        {
          'catname': "Tag 1"
        },
        {
          'catname': "Tag 2"
        },
    ],
    "comment": [
        {
            'comment': "Here be a comment"
        },
        {
            'comment': "Here is one two"
        },
    ],
},
{ 
    "post_title": "Post 2 ", 
    "cat": [
        {
        'catname': "Tag 1"
        }
    ],
    "comment": [],
}
...
]
```

**Answer**
To solve this problem use **Eager loading** 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Thank you Tim Lewis & Alec Joy!

Comment: Showing the structure of your output is great, but generally it helps to include the code that generates the output, like `Post::with('tags') ...`, or `Tag::with('post') ...`, etc. That way, we can help debug how you got the output vs how you want the output.

Comment: Have you already tried Post::with(['tags, comments'])->get();

Comment: Wow, how incredibly simple, including me! This is how its done. I wish I could give you both a 100 points.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, use [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

*(posted as community wiki-answer because this question has been answered by the asker)*